# How to animate FloatingActionButton on different devices and get same result?

Tags: android, android-animation

I tried animate floatingActionButton to get a menu in android but in devices with API<21 get some translation and API>=21 the translation is smaller.
I got this code:

```
private void translate(View view, float factor, int time){

    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, factor * view.getHeight(), 0);
    translate.setDuration(time);

    view.startAnimation(translate);

}
```

and after this just call method translate()

```
FloatingActionButton fab_mini = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_3);
translate(fab_mini, 1.5f, 400);

fab_mini.setTranslationY(-fab_mini.getHeight() * 1.5f );
fab_mini.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
fab_mini.setClickable(true);
```

The problem is the buttons show one over other in some devices (i tried in Android 5.0.1) and in others devices (Android 4.3 and 4.2.2) the buttons show with the correct space between theirs (0.5 * button.getHeight() or what is the same translation = 1.5).

Answer (score 0):

May be is because these parameters are pixels. Try to convert them to dp with this function:

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: I tried but useless.
The parameters for TranslateAnimation() constructors have dimensions on pixel(px) or independent pixel(dp)??
View.getheight() returns pixels, but i dont know if TranslateAnimation constructor needs px or dp for animation.